# how make filter for javascript carousel functional

Tags: javascript, html, css

JavaScript carousel for work section which should display all my work by default in **"All Work"** but when a user clicks on **App work** only app work should display and when a user clicks on **web work** only web work should display.

The filter property of **"All Work"**, **"App Work"**, **"Web Work"**
is not functional and I have *no idea* how to make that work.

#### check how its look on the website [view link](https://shahbajjamil.github.io/JavaScript-Carousel/)

#### source file[GitHub Link](https://github.com/shahbajjamil/JavaScript-Carousel/)

#### GitHub issues[Link](https://github.com/shahbajjamil/JavaScript-Carousel/issues/1)

### Buttons are not doing anything.

I need that when **"All Work"** get click both slides appear one after other in sequence  **"App Work"** then **"Web Work"**.
and when **"App Work"** gets click all carousel slides of **"App Work"** will appear one after other in sequence.
and when **"Web Work"** gets click all carousel slides of **"Web Work"** will appear one after other in sequence. **like a filter.**

### what I have tried

**but not get the desired result**

1. Adding css style
   `.hide { display: none; }`
   with the above method, the size of the slides remains there.
2. Adding innerHTML for **Web Work** button

```js
const myworkBuild = document.querySelector(".mywork");
webWork.addEventListener("click", () => {
myworkBuild.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    myworkBuild.innerHTML +=
      '<div class="slide web"><div class="webWork"><div class="webSS">' +
      '<img src="dell.png" />' +
      '</div><div class="webContent">' +
      "<h2>>Web 2 slide</h2>" +
      "<p>Lorem ipsum Fugit eius nemo</p>" +
      '<div class="button">' +
      '<a href="#">Get Apk</a>' +
      '<a href="#">More Info</a>' +
      "</div></div></div></div>";
  }
});
```

3. Adding innerHTML with Array for **App Work** button

```js
const myworkBuild = document.querySelector(".mywork");
appWork.addEventListener("click", () => {
const appData = [
    [
      "WhatsApp-UI-Clone",
      "whatsapp3.gif",
      "Just simple UI clone of WhatsApp, This app is built with flutter.",
      "#getapplink",
      "https://github.com/shahbajjamil",
    ],
    [
      "WhatsApp-UI-2",
      "whatsapp3.gif",
      "Just simple UI clone of WhatsApp, This app is build with flutter.",
      "#getapplink",
      "https://github.com/shahbajjamil",
    ],
  ];

  myworkBuild.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < appData.length; i++) {
    myworkBuild.innerHTML +=
      '<div class="slide app"><div class="appWork"><div class="appSS">' +
      '<img src='+appData[i][1]+' />' +
      '</div><div class="appContent">' +
      "<h2>"+appData[i][0]+"</h2>" +
      "<p>"+appData[i][2]+"</p>" +
      '<div class="button">' +
      '<a href='+appData[i][3]+'>Get Apk</a>' +
      '<a href='+appData[i][4]+'>More Info</a>' +
      "</div></div></div></div>";
  }
});
```

with the above method `let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");` does not update, so the `slides.NodeLists.length` remain the same even though slide get change, which leads to the same number of carousel slides in all filters **"All Work"**, **"App Work"**, **"Web Work"**
when slides are less in number any section it displays empty carousel slide and when slides are more in any section it gets omit form carousel slide.

#### check how its look on the website [view link](https://shahbajjamil.github.io/JavaScript-Carousel/)

#### source file[GitHub Link](https://github.com/shahbajjamil/JavaScript-Carousel/)

#### GitHub issues[Link](https://github.com/shahbajjamil/JavaScript-Carousel/issues/1)

#### HTML code for **App Work**

```html
          <div class="slide app">
             <div class="appWork">
                <div class="appSS">
                  <img src="whatsapp3.gif" />
                </div>
                <div class="appContent">
                  <h2>App 2 slide</h2>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, delectus. 
                  </p>
                  <div class="button">
                    <a href="#">Get Apk</a>
                    <a href="#">More Info</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

#### HTML code for **Web Work**

```html
          <div class="slide web">
              <div class="webWork">
                <div class="webSS">
                  <img src="dell.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="webContent">
                  <h2>Web 2 slide</h2>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, delectus.
                    </p>
                  <div class="button">
                    <a href="#">View Site</a>
                    <a href="#">More Info</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

#### Please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could add visible and hidden classes for the visible ones and hidden ones respectively. Then you can query using slides.visible.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".slide.visible")
```

```css
.visible {
  display: block
}

.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

Comment: With this code, solve's the filter part problem so that users can toggle between **All work**, **App work**, **Web work**. But still, hidden element occupies space at the last of a carousel with blank/white carousel slide. ## check how its look on the website [view link](https://shahbajjamil.github.io/JavaScript-Carousel/)  ##source file[GitHub Link](https://github.com/shahbajjamil/JavaScript-Carousel/)

Comment: I think you are translating based on slides length which wold be always 5. You should translate based on visible slides length,